# How to automate Pan Gestures in android using appium

Tags: android, automation, appium, gesture

I have an android application with gesture features, I am doing automation for this application but got stuck in implementing pan gesture(using 2 fingers). As I know pan gesture is not implemented in appium, so tried to implement it using multitouch action but able to get swipe instead of pan gesture. Any solution on this topics will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour), have a look at the help center, in particular [how to ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). What part are you stuck on? What have you tried?

Comment: in case you are looking for a discussion you shall probably move it to https://discuss.appium.io/ or https://github.com/appium/appium/issues

Answer (score 0):

To perform pan gesture you have to Perform swipe gestures after performing zoom in gesture....

Comment: @Nilesh actually this is the answer..the question is how to automate pan gesture...and my answer is perform swipe gestures after zoom gesture...